# Main water valve shutoff

Tags: shutoff

The main shut off valve is white. What is the red valve for? Should I just close the red valve?
[image]

Comment: I would think the red valve is the main, it is before the extra pipe going down somewhere.  The white valve will not stop water from flowing in the top pipe, only from flowing into the inner pipe going down.

Answer (score 2):

THe red shut off may go to an irrigation system, but it should have an anti backflow provision.

There also may be another hose bib somewhere around the home, or even water provided to a shed or garage, a pool?

Have you looked around the home for other things that may use water?

Answer (score 1):

- Turn on every water-consuming device in the house.
- Turn off the red valve.
- Look for the device that no longer has water flowing to it. That's what this red valve controls.